# Is there an open source complete Java EE MDA framework?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, generator, mda

I'm looking for a Java EE MDA framework that generates a complete Java EE application.
I mean starting by modeling with some tool like magicdraw sybase PowerDesigner then it generates the java classes (hibernate or JPA if possible) and finally the presentation layer is generated based on the model.

ie:
Suppose my UML model has a class called Person (id, firstName, lastName), then the framework will generate the java source and the .class files. After that in the presentation layer I can let the CRUD operations be generated based on my model.

I have searched on the net but unfortunately [edit: could not find anything?] (except Spring ROO but it does not start from the UML model).

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on an UML to OpenXava transformation, where I generate the JPAs definitions and then I rely on OpenXava to generate the full application (following the same philosophy behind my [UMLtoDoctrine and UMLtoDjango](http://modeling-languages.com/target-platforms/) services).

Answer (score 0):

EMF contains various tools/frameworks to build Java EE system. You can use it for getting code for domain model (Texo, Teneo, CDO) and presentation layer too (EMF Forms). It works on ecore model and contains UML to Ecore means.